# can I look the same meaning of "combination"&"platter"?

Tags: vocabulary

As I am working in the restaurant,I 'v always heard customers saying "dinner platter" instead of saying "combination plate" which is written in our menu.so I'm a bit unclear about it or confused .Can anyone help me about it ? thanks.

Comment: I don't think that "dinner platter" is widely viewed as interchangeable with "combination platter" in everyday English. I would be confused, too, if I were waiting on a table and someone ordered the (unlisted) "dinner platter" rather than the (listed) "combination platter."  I think it is quite sensible under the circumstances to elicit the diner's confirmation by saying something along the lines of, "I'm sorry—do you mean the combination platter?" and then (if appropriate) pointing to that item in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen various "dinners" listed by number or arbitrary name in Tex-Mex, Indian, Greek, and Chinese restaurants in the US that would likely pass as "combination platters" in other establishments. If a customer orders a "dinner platter" in your restaurant and there's no question that a "combination platter" is meant, smile and take the order.